# OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability Centos 6.8

Tags: apache, ssl, server, openssl, centos6

I have a test server running Centos 6.8 and can't overcome this message when running a SSL Labs test: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=biduno.com&latest

> This server is vulnerable to the OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability
>   (CVE-2016-2107) and insecure. Grade set to F.

I believe it's to do with open openssl and I have the latest version OpenSSL 1.1.0c  10 Nov 2016.

Could it be to do with my Ciphers?

> SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 SSLCipherSuite
>   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:!RC4:HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:+TLSv1.1:+TLSv1.2:!MD5:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!ADH:!EDH:!AESGCM
>   SSLHonorCipherOrder on

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Regard
William

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Thank you jww. I have asked the same question over at  Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330837/openssl-padding-oracle-vulnerability-with-latest-openssl-1-1-0c